# How to create a plan guide for a prepared statement

Tags: prepared-statement

I have a vendor application that 100% uses prepared statements.  I want to create a plan guide to modify the behavior of a few queries.  Extended events shows the statement I want to modify with an event type of "sp_statement_completed" and gives an object type of "PREPARED".  When creating a plan guide, do I choose SQL or OBJECT?  SQL doesn't work and OBJECT requires a Scope object name

I've tried both SQL and Object scope types.  SQL creates the plan guide but it is never used when running the application.  An error is generated when using Object scope type because of no object name.